# MYSQL: LIKE with Except Condition

Tags: mysql, database

I need some help. I want to show database that has name `"sample"` but except `"sample"` with `"fallback"` word.

```
Database Name
  sample_1
  2_sample
  sample_fallback
  samsple_2
  s_sample
  fallback_sample
```

I just want to get:

```
sample_1
2_sample
samsple_2
s_sample
```

What should I add from this query?

```
  "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%sample%';"
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?  Are you not getting back the results you expect?  What *are* you getting back?

Comment: You can try regexp  refer this http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/

Comment: @EricTaylor the problem is that the results is
 **sample_1
  2_sample
  sample_fallback
  samsple_2
  s_sample
  fallback_sample**

i want only (without fallback word)
    **sample_1
     2_sample
     samsple_2
     s_sample**

what should i add on that query inorder to get that output

Comment: @xXxrk04 I see.  I would agree with vijay4vijju: Take a look at REGEXP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to query the `information_schema` directly to get this list.

```
select schema_name 
  from information_schema.schemata
 where schema_name like '%sample%'
   and schema_name not like '%fallback%'
```

`SHOW DATABASES` isn't flexible enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%sample%' AND NOT LIKE '%fallback%';
```